# How do Group by a child property of a child property that may be null?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

How could I go about grouping the following?

```
people.GroupBy(p=>p.Addresses.GetFirstOrDefault().State);
```

without it failing on people who don't have an Address?

- can it be done in one statement?
- if not, do I have to first get a Distinct() list of all the various addresses members? How? (actually -- even if a is possible -- would be great to also learn how to do b :-) )
- I havn't seen it, but is there something equivalent to a GetFirstOrNew() that can be used to instantiate and return a non-null?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in one statement, yes:

```
// Set up whatever you need
Address dummyAddress = new Address { State = "" };

people.GroupBy(p => (p.Addresses.GetFirstOrDefault() ?? dummyAddress).State);
```

Alternatively, you might want to write a helper method:

```
public string GetState(Address address)
{
    return address == null ? null : address.State;
}
```

Then you can use:

```
people.GroupBy(p => GetState(p.Addresses.GetFirstOrDefault()));
```

Comment: Thanks very much Jon. Answered my question perfectly.

Comment: That said, I'm wondering about one more case related to the above. 
With n Person, and each Person allowed to be in n states...you showed how to handle non-state cases. What if a person lives in two states? How can I GroupBy not just the FirstOrDefault?

Comment: Just figured out it probably has something to do with people.SelectMany(p=>p.Addresses); (although not yet sure of what else...)

Comment: @Ciel: Grouping by a *set* is pretty tricky. It's easy enough if you have a limited number - e.g. for 2 you could do `GroupBy(p => new { State1 = ..., State2 = ... })`